# Windows 7 very slow installing new usb devices

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers

I'm find an issue on some machines I administer where, upon plugging in a USB device, Windows takes forever 'searching preconfigured driver folders' for the device driver. This includes USB disks, which I would imaging should be quite fast. I have configured the machines *not* to use Windows Update to look for the drivers, which sped things up on some machines, but it still seems to be taking way too long to recognise a simple USB device. Once installed, re-plugging the same device into the same USB port is very fast, but plugging it into a different port on the same machine gets the same issue. The C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore directory weighs in at almost 1 GB - not too much bigger than a clean install on that machine type (830 MB) (a clean windows install on this hardware installs devices super-fast).

Any ideas/pointers?

Comment: Have you found solution? My PC does exactly the same thing - stays on this screen for several minutes: http://vvcap.net/db/xffabrHH3_BdGlKh5HZR.htp

Comment: Gah; we did fix it, but can't find it in my docs :-/ I think it may have been a windows update or a hotfix; check the microsoft forums perhaps.

Answer (score -1):

all what you have to do is /Turn Off Windows Automatic Updates on Windows   following this steps it's work and problem will be fix it

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X0IfxzkABrY

Comment: Just providing an external link and not explaining what steps OP needs to follow is not a good practice. Please edit your answer with a full description of steps what eventually solve the issue.

Comment: Please quote the essential parts of the answer from the reference link(s), as the answer can become invalid if the linked page(s) change.